# How to sum up two Bangla (UTF-8) numbers in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to sum two utf-8 bangla number .
Here is the code :

```
<?php 
$a = ১২; //(12)
$b = ৫; //(5)
echo $c = $a + $b; //OUTPUR 17
?>
```

I need the outpur but now its show 0 so how can I do it ?
Advance thanks to all

Comment: and you want to output 17 or a 17 equivalent in bangla?

Comment: 17 in bangla like ১৭ :)

Comment: I don’t think PHP has any native support for this kind of thing. (Code as shown is only gonna throw errors such as "Use of undefined constant ১২" at you.) You will need to convert those to "normal" numbers first, before you can perform mathematical operations on them. http://bits.mdminhazulhaque.io/php/convert-number-between-banlga-and-english-in-php.html

Comment: @CBroe maybe intl extension would be a good choice

Comment: @hassan yeah, good suggestion (+1 for answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just simply do it like that, you need to convert them to normal digits first:

```
class Converter 
{
    public static $bn = ["১", "২", "৩", "৪", "৫", "৬", "৭", "৮", "৯", "০"];
    public static $en = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];

    public static function bn2en($number)
    {
        return str_replace(self::$bn, self::$en, $number);
    }

    public static function en2bn($number)
    {
        return str_replace(self::$en, self::$bn, $number);
    }
}

$a = '১২'; //(12)
$b = '৫'; //(5)

$c = Converter::bn2en($a) + Converter::bn2en($b); // $c = 17
echo Converter::en2bn($c); // ১৭
```

Credit to here: http://bits.mdminhazulhaque.io/php/convert-number-between-banlga-and-english-in-php.html

Comment: your code have problem update 

$c = Converter::bn2en($a) + Converter::en2bn($b); // $c = 12
to
$c = Converter::bn2en($a) + Converter::bn2en($b); // $c = 17

Comment: YES ITS WORK PERFECT THANKS :)

Answer (score 3):

another approach by using [*`intl`*](http://php.net/intl) extension :

```
// create a format from ba local
// you can get all available locales by : print_r(IntlCalendar::getAvailableLocales());
$format = numfmt_create('ba', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);

$a = numfmt_parse($format, '১২');
$b = numfmt_parse($format, '৫');
echo $c = $a + $b;
```

Output : 17